# Disable printer in Windows temporarily?

Tags: printer, windows-11, network-printer

I have a printer at home and in the past, I managed to accidentally print things on it. In Windows, you can simply print something via right-click and I managed to hit that too.

**Is there a way to disable the printer temporarily?**

I can also print via my phone, but it's a struggle to download each file to it when I want to print. And printing from my phone takes a very long time to complete. One page takes several seconds to finish - while it only takes under a second via PC.

Comment: You can disable the printer in Device Manger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause the printer, this will still allow jobs to be queued, but they won't be processed until the printer is unpaused. To do this, right-click on your printer and select "See what's printing," then click "Pause printing."

Comment: Long overdue, but this proved to be the solution. Mind you, finding Print Queue where you can pause & resume on Windows 11 is a major pain. I go to "Print Management", "All Printers" and there i can right click + pause / resume.